# Operar con valores obtenidos mediante Eval() en .aspx

Tags: c#, asp.net, embebido, aspx

tengo un problema que no sé si tenga solución de la manera que lo estoy enfrentando.

Tengo un repeater donde bindeo mediante <%# Eval('propiedad')%> propiedades de un objeto, el cual tiene entre todas, DateTime fechaInicio y DateTime fechaFin.

Lo que yo quisiera es escribir en el HTML las horas de diferencia que tienen entre sí esas 2 propiedades, para lo cual pensé en hacer algo así,

```
<%TimeSpan diferencia = ((DateTime)Eval("finaliza")) - ((DateTime)Eval("publicada"));%> 
<%= diferencia.TotalHours %>
```

lo cual no me funciona y por eso acudo aquí para buscar una solución que funcione. En lo posible que sea mediante este acercamiento que tuve, y si no es posible entonces escucharé otras opciones.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: A que exactamente te refieres cuando dices que no te funciono?

Comment: Me dice: Los métodos de enlace de datos como Eval(), XPath() y Bind() sólo se pueden utilizar en el contexto de un control de enlace de datos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo solucioné, era más simple de lo que pensaba:

```
Horas: <%# ((TimeSpan)(((DateTime)Eval("finaliza")) - ((DateTime)Eval("publicada")))).TotalHours%>
```

Answer (score 0):

Si tienes un objeto podrias definir una propiedad readonly que exponga ese dato calculado

```
public class Class1 { //aqui seria la clase que defines
   //resto propiedade

   public int Horas {
      get{ return this.finaliza.Subtract(this.publicada).TotalHours; }
   }
}
```

entonces en el html usarias

```
Horas: <%# Eval('Horas')%>
```

ealuas la propiedad que expone la clase

Comment: Sí cierto, muchas gracias, creo que voy a ir por ese lado, pero volviendo a como lo estaba pensando, es imposible hacerlo? o hay alguna forma muy rebuscada de lograrlo?

Comment: hay varias formas de lograrlo el tema es que estas dentro del binding de un repeater, por ejemplo el <%=  no aplica, que es lo que usaste al principio, por eso funciono cuando cambiaste a <%#